# How to resize images in windows phone 8 applications?

Tags: image, windows-phone-8, writeablebitmapex

How to Resize the image in windows phone 8.0 application using C# without loss of quality and to display full image

What I did,

My XAML Code:

```XAML
<StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
    <TextBlock Text="Select Image" FontSize="45" Height="106"></TextBlock>
    <Image Name="ImgPrev" Height="455" Stretch="None" ></Image>
</StackPanel>
```

---

My C# code

```C#
public MainPage()
{

    InitializeComponent();

    // Sample code to localize the ApplicationBar
    //BuildLocalizedApplicationBar();

    BitmapImage image = new BitmapImage();
    image.SetSource(Application.GetResourceStream(new Uri(@"Assets/Bug.jpg", UriKind.Relative)).Stream);
    image.DecodePixelType = DecodePixelType.Logical;
    image.CreateOptions = BitmapCreateOptions.BackgroundCreation;
    image.CreateOptions = BitmapCreateOptions.DelayCreation;
    Image img = new Image();
    img.Source = image;
    WriteableBitmap wb = new WriteableBitmap(image);
    wb.Resize(1000, 1000, WriteableBitmapExtensions.Interpolation.Bilinear);
    using(MemoryStream stream=new MemoryStream())
    {
        wb.SaveJpeg(stream, 1000, 1000, 0, 100);
        BitmapImage resize = new BitmapImage();
        resize.SetSource(stream);
        ImgPrev.Source = resize;
    }

}
```

---

The original image
Actual size of the image is 38 MB, Dimention 10240x6400 , height:10240, width:6400

[image]

What result I am getting is below image
[image]

Comment: Does the same issue happen with other images?

Comment: you wanted to resize the image is it? Can't you resize it through XAML? or wanted to resize it dynamically?

Comment: I think that is the correct image for 455 height and Stretch="None".  Try changing the Stretch to Fill.

Comment: I tried by changing stretch to fill.But it is not working.I want to resize image dynamically.